# Problema em SELECT INNER JOIN. Aparecendo ID ao invés do nome

Tags: sql, relacionamento, inner-join

Olá. Gostaria que em um resultado SELECT INNER JOIN fosse mostrado o nome do registro ao invés do ID do mesmo. Pesquisei em vários tópicos tratando o assunto aqui, porém não consigo resolver este problema. Tenho 4 tabelas onde no caso 3 delas estão relacionadas com uma tabela.

Abaixo segue uma descrição das 4 tabelas mencionadas:

```html
tbl_tipos
----------------
tipo_id
tipo

tbl_categorias
-----------------
categoria_id
categoria

tbl_subcategorias
------------------
subcategoria_id
subcategoria
categoria_fk

tbl_produtos
------------------------
produto_id
tipo_fk
categoria_fk
subcategoria_fk
nome
descricao
```

O que ocorre é que ao fazer o SELECT INNER JOIN conforme abaixo, não aparece o nome do registro relacionado a tbl_produtos e sim o ID:

```html
SELECT tbl_produtos.*, tbl_tipos.tipo, tbl_categorias.categoria, tbl_subcategorias.subcategoria
FROM tbl_produtos
INNER JOIN tbl_tipos ON tbl_produtos.tipo_fk = tbl_tipos.tipo_id
INNER JOIN tbl_categorias ON tbl_produtos.categoria_fk = tbl_categorias.categoria_id
INNER JOIN tbl_subcategorias ON tbl_produtos.subcategoria_fk = tbl_subcategorias.subcategoria_id;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De que maneira devo proceder para mostrar o nome ao invés do ID? Obrigado.

Comment: Creio que o que está sendo exibido são os campos categoria_fk e subcategoria_fk de tbl_produtos, já que você colocou tbl_produtos.* em seu SELECT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente fazer dessa forma, dei uma organizada na consulta para melhor compreensão, recomendo que você utilize [Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) para que a consulta fique mais clara e mais fácil de entender.

```
SELECT A.nome, A.descricao, B.tipo, C.categoria, D.subcategoria               
FROM tbl_produtos A
INNER JOIN tbl_tipos B ON A.tipo_fk = B.tipo_id
INNER JOIN tbl_categorias C ON A.categoria_fk = C.categoria_id
INNER JOIN tbl_subcategorias D ON A.subcategoria_fk = D.subcategoria_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT P.*
      ,T.tipo
      ,C.categoria
      ,S.subcategoria
  FROM       tbl_produtos      P
  INNER JOIN tbl_tipos         T ON P.tipo_fk         = T.tipo_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_categorias    C ON P.categoria_fk    = C.categoria_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_subcategorias S ON P.subcategoria_fk = S.subcategoria_id;
```

Os campos `categoria_fk` e `subcategoria_fk` são campos que armazenam o ID para fazer o vinculo entre as tabelas.

Para exibir utilize os campos `categoria` e `subcategoria` que são os campos que armazenam a descrição que você quer.

**Atenção**

Se não for obrigatório o produto possuir categoria e subcategoria, utilize o `LEFT JOIN` ao invés de `INNER JOIN`, pois se não, os produtos sem categoria ou subcategoria não serão retornados em seu select

Se não conhecer os tipos de join você pode dar uma olhada [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

> **INNER JOIN**
>   Esse é um formato comum de join, que retorna dados apenas
>   quando as duas tabelas tem chaves correspondentes na cláusula ON do
>   join.
>
> **LEFT JOIN**
>   É um dos formatos mais usados de join, que retorna a
>   Tabela A inteira e apenas os registros que coincidirem com a igualdade
>   do join na Tabela B (ou campos nulos para os campos sem
>   correspondência).

Comment: +1 e boa observação sobre o uso do outer join.